# C++ : how to return the value from an out of bounds array with exception handling?

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, try-catch

I am having trouble returning the value of an out of bounds array using an exception formalism.

I create an array object in my main script with for example length 10 using a class Array. Than I try to set the 11th element of the array to a certain value. In my class Array I throw back a value from a class ArrayOutOfBounds when the index of an array is larger than the size of the array, which is true in this case. In my main script I than catch this object from the ArrayOutofBounds class to give the out of bounds index and a terminal message that states that the array is out of bounds. However, how do I return the actual value I was trying to set the 11th element to?

It looks as follows:

class ArrayOutOfBounds + overloading operator << function

```
class ArrayOutOfBounds {
public:

ArrayOutOfBounds(int index) : _index(index) {} ;

int index() const { return _index ; }

private:
int _index ;
} ;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const ArrayOutOfBounds& m) {
  return (os << "Array index is out of bounds") ;
}
```

Throw back function within class Array:

```
double& operator[](int index) {
if(index > _size) {
    ArrayOutOfBounds aoob(index) ;
    throw aoob ;        
}
return _arr[index] ;
```

Main script:

```
int main() {

Array array(10) ;

try {
    array[11] = 10 ;
}

catch(ArrayOutOfBounds aoob) {
    cout << '\n' ;
    cout << aoob << " (index, value): " << aoob.index() << ", " << 10 << endl ;
}

cout << '\n' ;
return 0 ;
}
```

I tried to add a second throw value that throws _arr[index] but I understood you can't throw two things at once.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code an made sure you are hitting the exception? And shouldnt it be index >= _size?

Comment: OT: Terminology - C++ programs are not *scripts*. Also variable names beginning with `_` are reserved by the standard.

Comment: If you inherit from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) you can `override` the [`what`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) method to write out whatever you'd like, including the index.

Comment: The assignment expression is never evaluated, because the exception is thrown during the evaluation of `array[11]`. So you don't have access to the other operand of the assignment expression.

Comment: @Galik Names beginning with `_` *followed by capital letter*. Or containing double underscore.

Comment: @thorsan yes the exception code is working as it is supposed to do

Comment: @CoryKramer I can do that, but that is not really a nice solution right?

Comment: @Kerrek SB so I should make a separate exception to catch the value?

Comment: @user_537: I don't believe that's what I said, or what I meant. I don't think you *can* see the to-be-assigned value at all in the current setup. The only approach I can think of would be to modify your `[]`-operator to return a proxy object and have that proxy throw the exception on assignment.

Comment: @KerrekSb yes sorry I was to fast in replying to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with the `operator[]` as it is currently written because the exception is thrown before there is any attempt to assign a value to the reference.

Instead of using `operator[]` you could write a different member function to set values that takes two parameters, an index and a value:

```
void setAt(int index, double value) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= values.size())
        throw ArrayOutOfBounds{index, value}; 
    values[index] = value;
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/weA01DkX09jI3WQZ).

You *could* change `operator[]` so that it returns a proxy object that can be in an "out-of-bounds" state and then only when you try and assign a value to that proxy object is the exception thrown:

```
ArrayElementProxy operator[](int index) {
    return ArrayElementProxy{*this, index};       
}

class ArrayElementProxy {
    Array* array_;
    int    index_;
public:
    ArrayElementProxy(Array& array, int index) : array_(&array), index_(index){}
    Array& operator=(double value){
        array_->setAt(index_, value);
        return *array_;
    }
    operator double() const{
        return array_->getAt(index_);
    }
};
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/N3fPSqb2JrAs27w5)

But I think proxy objects are generally best avoided (just ask anyone who has tried to use `vector<bool>`).

Answer (score 3):

> However, how do I return the actual value I was trying to set the 11th element to?

You are not setting anything with the function.  Since the function returns a reference your class has no idea what the caller is doing with it.  It could be setting a value, making a copy, passing it to a function, it just can't know.  If you need to know then you need to rewrite the operator to overload the function operator `()` and then you can take in the index and the value you want to set at the index.

You can then modify the `ArrayOutOfBounds` to take in two parameters.  The index and the value and then you can access them inside the catch block.

Comment: Yes thank you, I was indeed already thinking along this track